# Embedded If Then Else behaving differently then Iif

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, null

I have this function in my embedded code

```
Function IsNull(ByVal Input As Double, ByVal D As Double) As Double
    If IsNothing(Input) Then
        Return D
    Else
        Return Input
    End If
End Function
```

I am using it to replace expressions like this

```
Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value), 1, Fields!Amount.Value)
```

I thought they would do the same thing, but they don't. When I put this expression in my report

```
=Code.IsNull(Fields!Amount.Value, 1) = Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value), 1, Fields!Weight.Value)
```

I get "False" when `Fields!Amount.Value` is `NULL`.

My guess is that something wonky is going on when I pass in a `NULL` to `Input` which is typed as a `Double`. But I don't know enough about VB to know what's actually going on.

Comment: You should use [IsDbNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of testing for Nothing. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Function IsNull(ByVal Input As Object, ByVal D As Double) As Double
    If IsNothing(Input) Then
        Return D
    Else
        Return CDbl(Input)
    End If
End Function
```

or:

```
Function IsNull(ByVal Input As Double?, ByVal D As Double) As Double
    If Not Input.HasValue Then
        Return D
    Else
        Return Input.Value
    End If
End Function
```